# Wait for a keypress to continue the function?

Tags: javascript, function

how can I make my javascript function wait for the user to press a key in the keyboard to continue the script? I am using a prompt to make the player move on the grid, but i want to use just the keys.

This code doesn't wait for the user to press a key, it goes directly to the prompt.

```
this.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    var option = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    alert(option);
};
var option = prompt("You can move tiping: \na(left)\nd(right)\nw(up)\ns(down).", "");
hero_can_move = true;
if(option=='w' || option =='a' || option=='d' || option=='s'){
    move(option);
}
```

Comment: IO in JavaScript is async - you can't make your script wait for it. You need to use an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a function to bind and event to keypresses

> keycodes:
>
> left arrow 37
>
> up arrow 38
>
> right arrow 39
>
> down arrow 40

```
   //how it would look in jquery
    $(window).on("keypress", function( key) {
        if(key == 37){ move("left");}
        if(key == 38){move("up");}
        if(key == 39){move("right");}
        if(key == 40){move("down");}
       });
```

Bind the event to the window, so that when you click a button, the window listens. nothing will happen unless a key that meets the if()criteria is pressed.

(note, Every time a key is pressed, the window key press function will fire and test all the contained if's. Some would consider this bad practice, but I honestly don't think it's even remotely notably bad performance in any modern computer)